# Best books to learn Google app engine and GWT?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Can you recommend some great book to learn how to make app with web services for the Google app engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found Programming Google App Engine by Dan Sanderson very immersive and thoughtful. His treatment of the topic is in-depth and goes beyond hello world programs. I recommend this book for all those who want to learn GAE in-depth. This book is very GAE specific and hence concentrates on both Java and Python API's. You fill find very little content on GWT in this book.

If you are a GWT beginner there is Robert Hanson's GWT in Action.

In addition to the 2 books Google has a number of good articles/dev videos on the respective SDK sites, which will help you to get started. It all depends on how much time you have in your hands, If you are short of time, learn GWT from Google's tutorials and totally skip the GWT book, and concentrate on mastering GAE and Datastore. You can always learn GWT on the way.

I do not know of any book which covers GAE + GWT in depth.

Comment: GWT in Action is good, but it's pretty out of date by now. There have been a multitude of features introduced in the last three years, none of which are in the book (e.g., UIBinder, ClientBundle, code splitting, lots more). I don't know any good up-to-date GWT books, but there's a good amount of online documentation.

Comment: You are right :) Google's own online documentation on GWT 2.0 should more than suffice.

Comment: is there  "to pdf" button I am missing somewhere?  the online documentation is great if you are online.  Not so much if you are not.

Comment: In that case you might consider downloading a mirror of the doc section. There is always a way around any problem, but only if you are looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Programming Google App Engine, Dan Sanderson, O'Reilly Media, November 2009](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596522735/)

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine Java and GWT Application Development by Daniel Guermeur and Amy Unruh (Nov 24, 2010)